# How to handle FileNotFound error when using img tag using mark_safe in django admin

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-admin

I am importing images into AWS S3 using django-storages. However, if Django admin does not have the corresponding image in S3, Admin would like to issue a FileNotFoundError to correct the S3BotoStorage object or fix the underlying problem to handle the error.

##### admin/hospital.py

```
class HospitalAdmin(OrderedInlineModelAdminMixin, IdFieldIncludedModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name", "tags_comma_separated", "created_at")
    list_display_links = ("name",)
    list_filter = [TagFilter]
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {"fields": ("user",)}),
        (
            None,
            {
                "fields": (
                    "logo_image",
                    "logo_image_width",
                    "logo_image_height",
                    "logo_image_preview",
                    "name",
                    "description",
                    "address",
                    "longitude",
                    "latitude",
                    "near_station_name",
                    "phone_number",
                    "sms_phone_number",
                )
            },
        ),
        (
            None,
            {
                "fields": (
                    "created_at",
                    "updated_at",
                )
            },
        ),
    )
    readonly_fields = [
        "logo_image_width",
        "logo_image_height",
        "logo_image_preview",
        "created_at",
        "updated_at",
    ]
    
    ...

    # FileNotFound Error occurs in the lower part
    @display(description="preview log image")
    def logo_image_preview(self, obj):
        return mark_safe(
            '<img src="{url}" width="{width}" height="{height}" />'.format(
                url=obj.logo_image.url,
                width=obj.logo_image.width,
                height=obj.logo_image.height,
            )
        )
```

I added a try/except statement to the error part to generate a correct error, but it doesn't seem to solve the fundamental problem

```
try:
            return mark_safe(
                '<img src="{url}" width="{width}" height="{height}" />'.format(
                    url=obj.logo_image.url,
                    width=obj.logo_image.width,
                    height=obj.logo_image.height,
                )
            )

        except FileNotFoundError as e:
            return str(e)
```

##### FileNotFound Error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoBGM.png)

##### Full Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://0.0.0.0:8080/admin/app/hospital/3093/change/?_changelist_filters=q%3D3093

Django Version: 3.2.16
Python Version: 3.10.8
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'rest_framework',
 'storages',
 'django_cleanup',
 'django_celery_beat',
 'ordered_model',
 'ckeditor',
 'ckeditor_uploader',
 'jsoneditor',
 'django_better_admin_arrayfield',
 'colorfield',
 'rangefilter',
 'import_export',
 'app',
 'drf_spectacular',
 'admin_auto_filters',
 'django_jsonform',
 'django_admin_inline_paginator',
 'mathfilters']
Installed Middleware:
['corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'app.middleware.RequestLoggingMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'app.middleware.SetIPAddressMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html, error at line 17
   File does not exist: dev/uploads/정면_1.jpg
   7 :         <div class="form-row{% if line.fields|length_is:'1' and line.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if not line.has_visible_field %} hidden{% endif %}{% for field in line %}{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">
   8 :             {% if line.fields|length_is:'1' %}{{ line.errors }}{% endif %}
   9 :             {% for field in line %}
   10 :                 <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="fieldBox{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if field.field.is_hidden %} hidden{% endif %}"{% elif field.is_checkbox %} class="checkbox-row"{% endif %}>
   11 :                     {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
   12 :                     {% if field.is_checkbox %}
   13 :                         {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
   14 :                     {% else %}
   15 :                         {{ field.label_tag }}
   16 :                         {% if field.is_readonly %}
   17 :                             <div class="readonly"> {{ field.contents }} </div>
   18 :                         {% else %}
   19 :                             {{ field.field }}
   20 :                         {% endif %}
   21 :                     {% endif %}
   22 :                     {% if field.field.help_text %}
   23 :                         <div class="help">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</div>
   24 :                     {% endif %}
   25 :                 </div>
   26 :             {% endfor %}
   27 :         </div>


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 608, in get_field
    return self.fields_map[field_name]

During handling of the above exception ('logo_image_preview'), another exception occurred:
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py", line 265, in lookup_field
    f = _get_non_gfk_field(opts, name)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py", line 296, in _get_non_gfk_field
    field = opts.get_field(name)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 610, in get_field
    raise FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name))

During handling of the above exception (Hospital has no field named 'logo_image_preview'), another exception occurred:
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 436, in _open
    f = S3Boto3StorageFile(name, mode, self)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 117, in __init__
    self.obj.load()
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 564, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 88, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 507, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 943, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)

During handling of the above exception (An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found), another exception occurred:
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/templates.py", line 74, in rendered_content
    return real_rendered_content.fget(self)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 214, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 195, in render
    return template.render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 172, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 214, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 214, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 315, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 315, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 988, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 671, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 796, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 858, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/helpers.py", line 212, in contents
    f, attr, value = lookup_field(field, obj, model_admin)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py", line 274, in lookup_field
    value = attr(obj)
  File "/Users/daehwi/PycharmProjects/sirs-backend/app/admin/hospital.py", line 113, in logo_image_preview
    width=obj.logo_image.width,
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/files/images.py", line 19, in width
    return self._get_image_dimensions()[0]
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/files/images.py", line 28, in _get_image_dimensions
    self.open()
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 76, in open
    self.file = self.storage.open(self.name, mode)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 41, in open
    raise e
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 39, in open
    return self._open(name, mode)
  File "/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 439, in _open
    raise FileNotFoundError('File does not exist: %s' % name)

Exception Type: FileNotFoundError at /admin/app/hospital/3093/change/
Exception Value: File does not exist: dev/uploads/정면_1.jpg
```

##### end traceback

```
/Users/daehwi/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/sirs-backend-5UU2jRwr-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py, line 439, in _open
    def _open(self, name, mode='rb'):
        name = self._normalize_name(self._clean_name(name))
        try:
            f = S3Boto3StorageFile(name, mode, self)
        except ClientError as err:
            if err.response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 404:
                raise FileNotFoundError('File does not exist: %s' % name) …
            raise  # Let it bubble up if it was some other error
        return f
    def _save(self, name, content):
        cleaned_name = self._clean_name(name)
        name = self._normalize_name(cleaned_name)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: A FileFoundError has occurred, and an image is attached to the body!

Comment: It helps if you share the full traceback.

Comment: Ok, I just shared a traceback!